# Disabling Chrome tab groups in Chrome v91

Tags: chrome-for-android, browser-tabs

A while back, I asked [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/229747/disabling-chrome-tab-groups) about disabling tab groups in Chrome v85. And that worked.

Now in Chrome version 91 they're back, with a vengeance. Trouble is, the flag that let me solve it last time is gone. The only flag that relates to tab groups is Tab Groups Continuation. And that's still disabled.

Is there a way of disabling them hiding away somewhere, or is this a lost cause?

Answer (score 3):

[This link](https://winaero.com/how-to-disable-tab-grouping-in-chrome-91-on-android/) detailed the following procedure, which worked:

1. Go to `chrome://flags`
2. Disable the flags `Temporarily expire M89 flags` and `Temporarily expire M90 flags`. This makes the flags in the next point appear.
3. After relaunching browser, search for the option `Tab Groups` and disable.
   Finally, search for the option `Tab Groups UI Improvements` and set it to disabled too.

Another two relaunches was necessary, but I once again seem to be group-less.

Comment: Didn't work for me :(