# Chrome new grid layout for tabs

Tags: chrome-for-android, browser-tabs

I've tried with *chrome://flags/#*
disabling *tab-grid-layout* reloading several times the browser, but no change works.

I've read a lot of articles on the web, some of them indicate this procedure, others to disable also flags like *tab-groups*, and so on, but currently nothing seems to work. (In fact, *tab-groups*, on the last Chrome realise, isn't available.)

Any solution?

Comment: Possible dupe: [Disabling Chrome tab groups in Chrome v91](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/238553/44325) with the flag reversed (expire -> unexpire; disable -> enable)

Comment: @AndrewT. Good answer, I've tried to unexpire both, but unfortunately it doesn't work anymore. It seems as the flags are only a residue of previous versions, and the values are bloked on *enable*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an answer, more of an information. Even if you find that flag and modify it as per your need, the very next version of Chrome may not have that flag at all. So, it is better to stick with what's provided or move to a new browser which fulfill your needs. Because after all we are not the controllers.

Comment: I hope that, because many users seem to require the previous cascade layout, Google will introduce the option, just as Samsung (if I correctly remember) already does

Comment: Yes. I'm one of them who wants cascaded layout. I liked previous android's "Recents" cascaded layout too. I don't like the one which we have now (iPhone's threw that layout in the trash and Google picked it up). People like to have options. Like they could keep the both the layouts as options (as classic & modern).